# How do I prevent commits from being removed from github?

Tags: github, revision-history

See title. Worst case, is there a way I can track the history of commit removals?

Comment: The best practice here, at least for critical branches such as `master`, is to never allow someone to do a direct push to that branch, and to force all changes to the branch to happen via a reviewed pull request.

Answer (score 1):

Like Tim Biegeleisen said, the best way to do this is to restrict push access to your repository, and only let people contribute to your repository through pull requests (which you can then monitor).

Answer (score 0):

**Add to Branch protection rules**

Define branch protection rules to disable force pushing, prevent branches from being deleted, and optionally require status checks before merging. New to branch protection rules?

Going to your repo settings -> branches -> add rule

[Configuring protected branches](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/configuring-protected-branches)

[Defining the mergeability of pull requests](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests)